# override a default function using client script erpnext

Tags: javascript, erpnext, frappe

In ERPNext v14 client script, I'm trying to override the amount function in quotation item which is quantity*rate by default but it does change for just seconds and then get back to the original formula

and the code i have is the following

```
function calculateAmount(frm, cdt, cdn) {
    var item = locals[cdt][cdn];
    var length = item.length;
    var width = item.width;
    var quantity = item.qty;
    var rate = item.rate;
    var amount = length * rate * width * quantity;
    console.log(amount);
    
    frappe.model.set_value('Quotation Item', cdn, 'amount', amount);
    console.log(item.amount)
}

frappe.ui.form.on('Quotation Item', {
    length: function(frm, cdt, cdn) {
        calculateAmount(frm, cdt, cdn);
    },
    width: function(frm, cdt, cdn) {
        calculateAmount(frm, cdt, cdn);
    },
    qty: function(frm, cdt, cdn) {
        calculateAmount(frm, cdt, cdn);
    }
});
```

i would like some help thank you in advance

Comment: What you can do is use refresh trigger to override the amount field after the system has recalculated it.

Comment: @Mahesh can you please explain more i don't understand

Comment: I usually add it in a timeout event. So ERPNext calculates and writes the amount then after a second my code overwrites it.

Comment: @TurkerTunali yes that exactly what i did

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're experiencing appears to be due to ERPNext overriding your custom amount calculation because the amount field's value is automatically calculated by the system each time there's a change in rate or qty.

What you can do is use refresh trigger to override the amount field after the system has recalculated it.

Here's your updated code:

```
function calculateAmount(frm, cdt, cdn) {
    var item = locals[cdt][cdn];
    var length = item.length;
    var width = item.width;
    var quantity = item.qty;
    var rate = item.rate;
    var amount = length * rate * width * quantity;
    frappe.model.set_value(cdt, cdn, 'amount', amount);
}

frappe.ui.form.on('Quotation Item', {
    length: function(frm, cdt, cdn) {
        calculateAmount(frm, cdt, cdn);
    },
    width: function(frm, cdt, cdn) {
        calculateAmount(frm, cdt, cdn);
    },
    qty: function(frm, cdt, cdn) {
        calculateAmount(frm, cdt, cdn);
    },
    rate: function(frm, cdt, cdn) {
        calculateAmount(frm, cdt, cdn);
    },
    refresh: function(frm, cdt, cdn) {
        calculateAmount(frm, cdt, cdn);
    },
});
```

n this updated script, the calculateAmount function is also called when rate is changed because your amount calculation depends on rate.

The refresh trigger is added so that the custom calculation for amount will be applied each time the form is refreshed, which includes after the system's automatic recalculation of amount.

This should help keep your custom amount in place.

Please note that this method might not be perfect, as ERPNext may still override the custom calculation in certain scenarios. For more control, you might need to modify the server-side Python code.